# Not getting SQL values from Linked Server (Oracle Database)

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, record, linked-server

I have an Oracle Database, Which is linked to an Microsoft SQL Server, so I can query the server and spool information from the database without worries directly from SQL Server Management Studio. Now I want to pass a SQL query to fetch information from the linked server and display the values from the database.

So when I do this for instance

```
select * from openquery(LinkServerName,'select * from table_name')
```

This works 100%, no errors nothing.

Now when I run something like this

```
select * from openquery(LinkServerName,'select foracid,acct_name,acct_crncy_code,clr_bal_amt from table_name where bacid='1010000001' and sol_id='XXX'')
```

Where bacid and sol_id are both strings as columns, I get this return error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near '1010000001'.

Please what do I appear to be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from openquery(LinkServerName,'select foracid,acct_name,acct_crncy_code,clr_bal_amt from table_name where bacid=''1010000001'' and sol_id=''XXX'' ')
```

should work, ' needs to be escaped by '' (two ').

Correction based on comment (escaping is somewhat strange in this case):

```
select *
from openquery(LinkServerName,'select 
foracid,acct_name,acct_crncy_code,clr_bal_amt from table_name where 
bacid=""1010000001"" and sol_id=""XXX"" ')
```

Comment: tells me invalid identifier

Comment: thanks i got it to work now , rather than '' i went ahead to make it double "" all seems good at this point. thanks again

Comment: exact message, complete message? does the query work direktly in the remote-db?